# How to bind Dropdown list by changing item in another dropdown in mvc using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to bind states based on country selection using jquery ajax and i am using just html select for states.

```
<select id="State" class="selectpicker" required>  
</select>  
@Html.DropDownList("Countries", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.CountryId, "Select", new { @class = "selectpicker", @readonly = "true" })

$('#Countries').on('change', function () {

        var CountryId = $('#Countries').val();
            $.ajax({
            url: "/Home/GetStates",
            data: JSON.stringify({
                CountryId: CountryId
            }),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",

            success: function (Result) {
                $.each(Result, function (item,index) {
                    console.log(index);
                    $.each(index, function (i) {

                        //$('#State').append($("<option></option>")
                        //   .attr("value", index[i].StateID)
                        //   .text(index[i].StateName));

                        //$('#State').append($('<option>', {
                        //    value: index[i].StateID,
                        //    text: index[i].StateName
                        //}, '</option>'));

                        var optionhtml = '<option value="' +index[i].StateID + '">' + index[i].StateName + '</option>';
                        console.log(optionhtml);

                        $("#State").append(optionhtml);

                        //$("#State").append($("<option></option>").text(index[i].StateName).val(index[i].StateID));
                    });


                }); 

            error: function (request, status, error) {
                alert("error occured -- "+request.responseText);
            }

        });
    });
```

the problem only is data not displaying as options.I have used different ways to loop through my results and create my select id=State. (those are commented in the above code)

Comment: What do you mean by 'binding'? Are you trying to display state information as options when a user selects a country? How is it not working for you? Are you getting a particular error or is it not giving you the desired result?

Comment: i did't  get any error and the result is perfect

Comment: I'm uncertain what you mean by 'binding', do you mind clarifying that a little bit?

Comment: it means displaying states information as options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<select class="selectpicker"></select>
```

it seems to be you are using bootstrap,so to programmatically update a select with JavaScript, first manipulate the select, then use the refresh method to update the UI to match the new state. This is necessary when removing or adding options, or when disabling/enabling a select via JavaScript.

```
use this:
$("#State").append(optionhtml).selectpicker('refresh');
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see comments on your existing code.

```
 $.each(index, function (i) {

                    //$('#State').append($("<option></option>")
                    //   .attr("value", index[i].StateID)
                    //   .text(index[i].StateName));

                    //$('#State').append($('<option>', {
                    //    value: index[i].StateID,
                    //    text: index[i].StateName
                    //}, '</option>'));

                    var optionhtml = '<option value="' +index[i].StateID + '">' + index[i].StateName + '</option>'; //this creates new variable for each item 
                    console.log(optionhtml);

                    $("#State").append(optionhtml); // current item will be appended. Also this needs to be replaced 

                    //$("#State").append($("<option></option>").text(index[i].StateName).val(index[i].StateID));
                });
```

Put var optionhtml before $.each.

replace

```
var optionhtml = '<option value="' +index[i].StateID + '">' + index[i].StateName + '</option>';
```

with this

```
optionhtml += '<option value="' +index[i].StateID + '">' + index[i].StateName + '</option>';



$("#State").append(optionhtml);   // needs to be placed after $.each ends
```

Comment: do you see the optionhtml values in your console?

Comment: what is this $("#State") look like after code is executed? is it empty?

Comment: also Why you have two $.each?

Comment: actually Result have list items so first $.each get list of items and second one will extract one by one

Comment: append the dropdown after your result each loop i.e. at the end

Comment: add some static value inside loop and see if that works. if yes, then there might be something wrong with data or you probably misplaced one piece of code that is causing the problem.